# CSS Alignment - covering next div

Tags: css

I HAD two divs on a page - an image and some text. Image is set to 100% width, so text stacks underneath it. No positions were set.

Then I added a title on top of my image, giving the container div a position of relative and the image and title a position of absolute.

This has caused my text that was below the image to disappear behind it. WHY?!?! I'm new to CSS and can't figure these alignments out.

CSS:

```
    .fullwidthimage {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.imageoverlay {
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    }
    .imageundertext {
        position:  absolute;
    }
```

jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/4ksbz4c2/

thanks.

Comment: You are using a combination of floats and absolute positioning such that it is hard to know what the layout is suppose to look like. Can you explain or provide an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "z-index" in your css.

If the image is fixed, I would set it as a background-image instead.

https://jsfiddle.net/4ksbz4c2/1/

```
.fullwidthimage {
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:-1;
  text-align:center;
}

.fullwidthimage img {
  z-index:-1;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
.fullwidthimage h1 {
  z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: That brings the text on top of the image, but I want it underneath the image, the next thing down the page.

Comment: Change the positions then, relative instead of fixed;   https://jsfiddle.net/4ksbz4c2/3/

Comment: OK, deleting the absolute position on the image (so it's just relative on the containing div and absolute on the overlying title) worked and retrieved my text to the bottom of the image again. But I don't understand why!! Can anyone explain?

Comment: Divs are set to relative position by default meaning they won't overlap.     class fullwidthimage & site-content will stack for that reason. Now you want the H1 element to overlap the image in fullwidthimage ; The image has a relative position [so it starts as higher on the left has possible] and the H1 is absolute to place it to a specific area within its parent. Please accept the answer above it you are satisfied with the answer ;)

Comment: OK, that makes sense, thanks. The only thing I'm still confused about is why if BOTH the h1 text and image are set to absolute, that causes the text beneath to go behind the relative containing div? 

I've accepted your fix, sorry I didn't realise you had to do that. I'm new to this!! Thanks.

Comment: As default divs are position:relative. The parent adapts to a relative child. Parents don't adapt to Absolute Childs ; so the Childs overlaps the parent which ends-up with a size of 0px tall and 0px wide.  That's why if you keep the image as position:relative, the parent sets up to the size of the child, pushing the other section [the one with the rest of the copy] bellow instead of behind.